# What is the reason for decomposition of layered cathode materials?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

Zhang [[1](https://doi.org/10.3389/fenrg.2014.00059)] and related publications claim oxygen can evolve from layered metal oxide cathode materials when charging the Li-ion battery.

Is it the high positive potential given to the cathode while charging pulling the electrons from the chemical bonds of the cathode materials and thus cause the decomposition to evolve oxygen?

If not, what is the cause of the evolution of oxygen?

#### Reference

1. Zhang, S. S. Insight into the Gassing Problem of Li-Ion Battery. *Front. Energy Res.* **2014**, 2. DOI: [10.3389/fenrg.2014.00059](https://doi.org/10.3389/fenrg.2014.00059).

Comment: As the particular portion of your linked document says, it is like so: 
 $$\ce{Li_xMO2 − 4δ e− -> Li_{x−4δ}MO_{2−2δ} + 4δ Li+ +δ O2}$$

Answer (score 1):

A cathode is the electrode where a reduction happens, whatever its working mode (cell or electrolysis). So when recharging a Li-ion battery, the $\ce{Li+}$ ion are going to the cathode to be reduced: reduction happens on the Li-graphite electrode (cathode). And no oxygen can be formed on this electrode. Oxygen may be produced by electrolysis at the other electrode made of cobalt and manganese oxides. These oxides are oxidized to a higher number of oxidation. But of course, these oxides are not very stable, they may lose part of their oxygen as $\ce{O2}$.

To summarize, the lithium electrode is always the negative pole, whatever its working mode. The lithium atom works as an anode when the cell is working (producing $\ce{Li+}$ ions and electrons), and as a cathode when the cell is being recharged. The other electrode is always the positive pole, whatever its working mode. Its metallic oxides are reduced when the cell is producing current (cathode). When being recharged, this electrode is an anode, as its oxides are oxidized to a higher oxidation number.

Comment: @Maurice You are generally right. But  to avoid confusion of terms in context of rechargable cells, assignment of the cathode/anode is conventionally decided to be taken always as if in the galvanic mode, not in the electrolytic mode. Therefore, the assignment is clear all the time.

Comment: @Poutnik. Are you sure of this interpretation ? I have never heard it before ! Can you justify it ?

Comment: @Maurice Is not it justified by the description ? // It is like if you talk the left and the right bank of the river. One approach is relative, which is on you left or right hand. The other approach is absolute, in geographical sense, along the stream. // Notice yourself whenever there is talked Li-Ion cell, when an anode is talked, it is **always** the graphite intercalate, and the cathode is **always** the metal oxide. as description of the cell  structure takes precedence over momentary functionality. // I would agree it is rather practical engineering approach than approach of phys. chem.

Comment: @Maurice It would make little sense, talking like "The electrode which is a cathode at charging or an anode at discharging" // Like "The river bank which is the left bank looking downstream or the right bank , looking upstream". It is just the left bank.